# Drupal webform into front page template

Tags: templates, drupal, drupal-webform

I need to add a webform to my page-home.tpl but I'm really new on Drupal so I need a really clear help...

I'm using DRUPAL 6 and I have created the webform.

I would like to add the webform to my custom template just adding the php code to the tpl file. My webform id is id="webform-client-form-20".

Can you help me ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

The quickest (not necessarily best) way to do it is using a combination of [`node_view()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_view/6) and [`node_load()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_load/6):

```
$nid = 20; // Node ID of the webform.
$webform_node = node_load($nid);
echo node_view($webform_node);
```

You'd be better off loading that into a variable in a preprocess function than outputting it directly in the theme but this should work for your purposes.

Comment: It was what I was looking for. Thanks!  Can you explain about the preprocess function? I'm reaaly noob on drupal...  EDIT: is this (http://drupal.org/node/223430) what you mean ?

Comment: @Uncoke: Yup, the link you've provided is exactly what I meant :)

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm on the right way, so if you have any suggestion feel free to told me. The code is working nice, but if I submit the form (for example with missing fields) I'm redirected to the 'original' webform node... instead I would prefer to stay on the front page. Can I override it ?

Comment: You could just pop into the settings for the webform node and set it to redirect to the home page instead?

Comment: I have forcet the redirect to <front> and is is working nice.  Now I have to undetstand how load the form messages like the submission or errors message... to publish on the front page after submission.  Do you have any suggestion about ?  Thanks a lot for your helpfully help!

Comment: No problem :) Have a look at [`drupal_set_message()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_set_message/6), that's the function Drupal core uses to display messages to the screen

Comment: Thanks Clive, this is nice but I'm a little confused... I'm not sure about use it... On webform> form setting > I have type the "Confirmation message" and I have set "<front>" as Redirection location. Then on Front page template I have add the code you posted yesterday and it works very nice.   But after submit the form... i have the front page reload and no "confirmation message" showen... My target is hide the form and show the message... but I'm unable ti do... :/

Comment: I'm really noob! I realized the redirect page was "<front>" but the action form was to form page '/?q=content/form'... and then this page do the last redirtect... to the <front>  Maybe this is the reason why I'm unable to load the form submission values... Maybe the right way was to set the form page as <front>...  hmmm   now I have to change again my template... using the form page as front page... :/